# Error while running a Java program

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I was trying to convert an array to a list and vice-versa and perform different methods of array and list respectively using the below code.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedList{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] things1 = {" seminar", " presentations", " hackathon", " movies"};
        LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(things1));

        theList.add("tickets");
        theList.addFirst("Hellow");

        things1 = theList.toArray(new String[theList.size()]);

        for(String x: things1)
            System.out.printf("%s", x);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I am running it from NetBeans it works correctly, but when I am trying it in normal text editor and running through terminal it gives an error:

```java
LinkedList.java:10: error: type LinkedList does not take parameters
LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(things1));
          ^
LinkedList.java:10: error: type LinkedList does not take parameters
LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(things1));
                                           ^
2 errors
```

I think the list should take parameter but the error is completely opposite.

Why is it so?

Comment: rename your class to something else other than `LinkedList`

Comment: "Error while running a Java program" No - that's an error while *compiling* a Java file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You import

```
java.util.*
```

And since there's a `java.util.LinkedList` in the standard libraries NetBeans seems to pick that one up instead while `javac` from the JDK uses your own `LinkedList` which doesn't take parameters (such as `String` in `LinkedList<String`). To fix this problem you can do one of the following

- Rename your class
- Wherever you use a `LinkedList` you put the full name such as `com.myproject.LinkedList` or `java.util.LinkedList` to make it explicit which one you want (replace `com.myproject` with the actual package that your own linked list is in)

Comment: The Import is not enought. you must add the package befor the classname, because the name iss not unique.

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer

Comment: Ok.that worked,thanks.But why did I have to change the classname??Please can you clarify?

Comment: If the java compiler knows about two classes with the same name, how does it know which one you want to use? It can't just decide on its own. That is why you need to tell it which version to use

Comment: So how was NetBeans able to decide?

Comment: I think that whenever `javac` and the IDE disagree, it's usually a bug in the IDE.